# How to edit a shapekeys lerp?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, shape-keys, pose-mode

Made a shape key to make my character get taller, it has a negative value (so they can be shorter as well). The animations look fine when the shape key causes the body to get taller but not when they get shorter.

I just need to move a couple verts on the -1 value on the shape key but If I go into edit mode it only allows me to edit the +1.

Is there a way to edit the -1 shape key's verticals? I just need my armature bone to be at the correct level for the dudes elbow when it gets shorter.

This is a dupe question cause the first time it went unanswered

Comment: Did you ask this question a few days ago and delete it?

Comment: I literally said this above: This is a dupe question cause the first time it went unanswered

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. In that case, please don't do that again. There are [several things you can do](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) when no one answers, but deleting and re-asking should not be one of them. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289858/user-deleted-question-with-my-answer-then-asked-question-again

Comment: If you don't got rep to get a bounty and I can't figure out how to fix it the question will get re-asked. That's just how it works.

Comment: I recommend not doing that. As noted on another StackExchange site, this behaviour may eventually lead to your suspension: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23042

Comment: I am literally incapable of caring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shape keys, Relative or Absolute, may only be edited at 1. That is their fixed point of reference. In the case of Relative shape keys, what is stored is the difference between that fixed point of reference and whatever is in the 'Relative To' field of the key.

Relative interpolations are linear. Setting a value outside 0-1 is calling for a linear *extrapolation*, beyond 0-1, of the imaginary straight lines in object space down which vertices travel between value 0 and value 1.

[image]

Using 'New Shape from Mix' in the menu under the little down chevron on the right of the keys list, you can take your -1 extrapolation of the 'Tall' shape key and make it into a key in its own right; say.. 'Short'.

You can now edit the Short key.

How you deal with the keys after that is up to you.. if you want to return to just 2 keys, you could, for instance, delete the Basis, and have a single relative key from 0=Tall to 1=Short, but beware, the whole journey (the new straight line) will not pass through what was 'Basis'before.

You may go for Absolute keys, perhaps re-ordering them. In that case 'Tall', 'Basis'and 'Short' will be put in a single continuum, and you will have to alter only one 'Evaluation Time' value to pass through all three reference shapes, (with a choice of interpolation methods)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.